# Валидация формы с исключением полей

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

У мен есть форма:

```
<form>

   <select>
    <option>Почта</option>
    <option>Доставка</option>
  </select>

  //Показать если выбрано почта
  <input name="Почта" formControlName='post'/>

  //Показать если выбрано доставка
  <input name="Доставка" formControlName='office'/>

</form>
```

Не могу понять как сделать валидацию такой формы:

```
this.payForm = new FormGroup({
      post: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      office: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
});
```

Если делать так валидацию, то форма будет всегда невалидна, так как 1 поле будет всегда скрыто!Возможно можно както удалять поля и добавлять из FormGroup, но не пойму как!

Comment: angularjs angular angular5 - каша

Comment: мне надо понять принцип,думаю он на все версиях один и тот же!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/angularjs/info  https://www.google.com/?q=angularjs%20angular2